# Select data based on date match between 2 tables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 tables, in one there are transactions in USD, in the other there are monthly USD<>CHF exchange rates.

I want to automate the picking of the correct exchange rate for a given date.

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCWBr.png)

The formula would be inserted into 'Table 1 - Exch. Rate' column.
It should check what date it is ('Table 1 - Date') and then check which 'USD<>CHF' matches the date in Table 2.
For example, for Jan 30th it would insert 0.93061.

I played around with 'Query' but can't make it work. Is this the way to do it or is ther a better function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go with a simple `vlookup` or `xlookup` function.

```
=index(if(len(A2:A),xlookup(A2:A,F:F,G:G,),))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
Is it possible to expand on this and add several currencies? Make it pull the data from the right currency table? Like on this image: https://ibb.co/dkPKqkJ

I guess all the data has to be in one long table, not split per currency

Comment: sure its possible to expand. it would help if you could share a sample sheet with test data for me to work it out.

Comment: Thanks, here an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LJz42G6AXBsjOybMTUoCvYSgELjRSnHGWPwcEi6PLg/edit

Comment: try: `=map(A2:A,C2:C,lambda(a,c,if(a="",,ifna(vlookup(a,choosecols(G:Q,IF(c="USD",{1,3},IF(c="GBP",{5,7},IF(c="ETH",{9,11})))),2,)))))` (https://i.imgur.com/R4pLn3H.png)

Comment: I very much appreciated your time, but I can't make it work on the main doc despite it working on test instances.
It gives me this error on some tabs while on others in the same doc it works: https://prnt.sc/0ecAks44joRo

It even renders my web version of sheets unresponsive and I have to go into the mobile one to remove the function and get my doc back...

Comment: Most likely the new function [CHOOSECOLS](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en) did not roll out for the country(locale setting) your sheet is set to. the global rollout is supposed to be done by Feb 15th

Comment: Then let's hope it will star working soon, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I see the issue arises if I have a currency which is not covered in the function. 
Can one add an error exception in there?

Comment: Please recreate the scenario in the sample sheet you shared above so that I can get a clear picture on what you are referring to and easily work on it.

Comment: Done. But it breaks the doc: https://prnt.sc/aZRx2wB0oDy8

Comment: maybe share fresh sheet with no formula. we can go ahead with a different formula

Comment: I removed the formula in the original (for some reason mobile does not break).
So you can access it again, I also added CHF, which would break the original formula: =map(A2:A,C2:C,lambda(a,c,if(a="",,ifna(vlookup(a,choosecols(G:Q,IF(c="USD",{1,3},IF(c="GBP",{5,7},IF(c="ETH",{9,11})))),2,)))))

Since there is no CHF in it.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/D93GzYB.png manually arrange the headers as shown in the screenshot and use this formula: `=map(A2:A,C2:C,lambda(a,c,if(a="",,ifna(vlookup(a,filter(G:Q,G1:Q1=c),2,)))))`

Comment: Thank you. 
Just to make sure I understand this setup correctly. Let's say I have 10 currencies in a list, I set up the rate table for 6 and for the other 4 I do not. The function will pull the data for the first 6, but will leave it blank for the other 4.

But can I then enter the rate manually for those 4 or will it break the function?

Comment: `vlookup(A2,filter(G:Q,G1:Q1=C2),2,)` use a drag-down formula instead of arrayformula and you can manually override the formula cells on need basis.

Comment: Did I do this wrong? https://prnt.sc/HuenvMtdvyQv

Comment: Just clear the cells once from D3 to downwards

Comment: Gives me the same result everywhere: https://prnt.sc/Uwn5eDD8oKJX
Tried $G$1:$Q$1=C2 but no good either

Comment: Just use `=vlookup(A2,filter(G:Q,G$1:Q$1=C2),2,)` in D2 and then drag-it down

Comment: That will work, I think :) Do you have a tipping page or ETH wallet I can send donate to?